# Node module ifx_db installation fails in linux

Tags: node.js, linux, database, informix, shared-objects

I am trying to install `ifx_db` (Node module to connect to `informix DB`). It is working fine in Windows but in `Linux` i am getting the following error.

```
/app/node_modules/ifx_db/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:88
        throw e
        ^

Error: libthcli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at bindings (/app/node_modules/ifx_db/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:81:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/ifx_db/lib/odbc.js:29:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

Request your inputs towards this
Thanks in advance

Comment: libthcli.so is missing apparently

Comment: Hi... Thanks for the reply...how to fix this issue? what am i supposed to do to add libthcli.so

Comment: I've never used Informix but I believe an Informix install should install libthcli. Did you install Informix previously ?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.odbc.doc/ids_odbc_023.htm

Comment: I think the system needs to know where the Informix libraries are installed.  You might do that by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or with `/etc/ld.so.conf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI:
The **Informix node.js drive** is depended on **Informix Client SDK version 4.10 xC2 or above**, that you need to download and install it separately. You may pick the latest version which is Informix CSDK 4.10xC9.

The **ifx_db will be a read only repository** for historic reference, **OpenInformix** is the new home; the URL for the Informix node.js driver is
https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxNode
The **Informix node.js** from **OpenInformix** can be installed by

```
npm install ifxnjs
```